# Do HTML email validation and Angular 2 work together?

Tags: html, angular, validation

I'm currently working on validations with Angular 2. I have some problems with HTML email and website validators and `valid` ngModel's property.

For example:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <input type="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="contact.email" name="email" >
    <button [disabled]="!form.form.valid" type="submit">Btn</button>
```

Every word i input is fine. `#email.valid` remains true as if no HTML5 validator existed:

```
{{#email.valid}} %%% true
```

So the form's button is enabled all the time. But when I hit the button the HTML warning comes out saying that the email field is invalid, so validation is working, but `#email.valid` it's still true.

Is it possible to use angular2's ngModel directive with HTML validators?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use both together, you can use them like this:

```
<input  id="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" class="form-control" type="email" ng-model="loginctrl.user.email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required/>
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$touched && myForm.email.$error.required"><b class="color">This is a required field</b></span> <span ng-show=" myForm.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid"><b class="color">This field is invalid</b></span>
```

Comment: Be careful, this it not a valid email pattern.  Does not accept top-level domains like .info  for example!

Comment: The question is asking about angular2 and the answer is angular1